# Does WINE support .wma playback through MCI?

Tags: audio, wine

This [application (zip file)](http://www.lickbyneck.com/Content/SoloGuitar/Pop22/LickByNeck-Love%20You%20Like%20A%20Love%20Song-Selena%20Gomez%20And%20The%20Scene-BASIC.zip) extracts .wma file but fails to play it under WINE. I have installed Windows Media Player 10 and it is able to play this embedded audio file under WINE, but it could use different API.

In the past I tried to configure MCI registry keys so that "wma"="MPEGVideo" in various ways trying to interpret available information, but always failed.

Call to `mciSendCommandW` I believe should return 0 in order to succeed. Can this possibly work? Does it work for anyone?

```
14118.930:002c:Ret  KERNEL32.GetDriveTypeW() retval=00000001 ret=7ecc7f66
14118.930:002c:trace:mci:mciSendCommandW => 00000119
14118.930:002c:Ret  winmm.mciSendCommandW() retval=00000119 ret=7e7bd553
14118.930:002c:Call user32.SetCursor(00000000) ret=7e7bd567
14118.930:002c:trace:cursor:SetCursor (nil)
14118.930:002c:Call winex11.drv.SetCursor(00000000) ret=7eb82fc6
14118.930:002c:Ret  winex11.drv.SetCursor() retval=00000000 ret=7eb82fc6
14118.930:002c:Ret  user32.SetCursor() retval=00020054 ret=7e7bd567
14118.930:002c:Call winmm.mciGetErrorStringW(00000119,0034bd44,00000100) ret=7e7b
```

... and error message that will show up in message box:

```
14118.930:002c:trace:resource:LoadStringW L"Cannot determine the device type from the given filename extension." loaded !
```

Answer (score 1):

Not by default but you can follow the instructions in this blog to enable it. The article is titled: [Enabling WMA support under Wine in Linux](http://www.romanstefko.com/2011/07/enabling-wma-support-under-wine-in.html). You'll have to download Windows Media Player 10 to do this.

Comment: Already have it, installing it did not help.

Comment: You might want to check this tutorial as well: http://thestrayworld.com/2010/04/23/how-to-convert-wma-lossless-to-flac-in-ubuntu-karmic/. But from the sound of it you may not be able to get playback working.

Comment: Also is your interest in just playing back .wma files?